# RShiny downloads an html file instead of csv file

Tags: r, shiny, download

I am trying to download a dtaframe as csv file but when I press download button, I come up with an html file. Could you please help me to download a csv file?  My code is below

Thank you

ui:

```
downloadButton(outputId = "clean_download", label = "Download cleaned data")
```

server:

```
output$clean_download <- downloadHandler(
    filename =  function() {
      paste('clean_data.csv', sep='')
    },
    
    content = function(filename) {
     write.csv(as.data.frame(train_cleaned()), filename, row.names=FALSE)
      
    } 
  )
```

Comment: What does the function `train_cleaned()` return, and is that a reactive function?

Comment: it is a reactive function which is a subset of a data frame

Comment: it return a dataframe

Comment: Are you running the app in the R Studio viewer?  Sometimes the download button does not work properly there with some versions.  Open the app in a browser and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: When I open shiny in browser, it worked properly. Thank you very much :))  @chemdork123

Comment: I remember this used to happen in my apps too, but I can't reproduce it now anymore (it works in the RStudio viewer).  I believe this issue was fixed - I recommend updating `shiny`, `R` and RStudio.  It should then be fixed.  I'm using Rstudio 1.3.959, `R` 4.0.2, and `shiny` 1.5.0.